# Absolute folder path in python

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I cannot get this code to work for me:

```
import os

# Define folder to search
searchFolder = "C:\Users\rohrl\OneDrive\Python\PictureCompare\MixedPictures"
os.chdir(searchFolder)
print(os.curdir)
```

I keep on getting a Unicode error on line 4. What am I doing wrong? I'm on a Windows PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"\"` character in Python is a string escape, and it introduces shortcuts for certain string characters. For example the string `"\n"` doesn't contain the characters `\ and n`. It contains a newline character. Windows paths always cause this trouble in Python. When Python sees `"\U"`, it's looking for some unicode escape that doesn't exist.

You can use raw strings in Python by prepending the string with `r`.

```
searchFolder = r"C:\Users\rohrl\OneDrive\Python\PictureCompare\MixedPictures"
```

Or you can get in the habit of using double `\\`. Python reads `\\` as a single `\`.

```
searchFolder = "C:\\Users\\rohrl\\OneDrive\\Python\\PictureCompare\\MixedPictures"
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. As I'm beginning to learn python this is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash - or use slashes.
Also I suggest You look at the pathlib Library (it does not help in this short example, but pathlib makes it more pythonic to work with file system objects) :

```
import os
import pathlib

# variant 1 - raw string
str_search_folder = r"C:\Users\rohrl\OneDrive\Python\PictureCompare\MixedPictures"
# variant 2 - escaping the backslash
str_search_folder = "C:\\Users\\rohrl\\OneDrive\\Python\\PictureCompare\\MixedPictures"
# variant 3 - my prefered, use slashes
str_search_folder = "C:/Users/rohrl/OneDrive/Python/PictureCompare/MixedPictures"

path_search_dir = pathlib.Path(str_search_folder)

os.chdir(path_search_dir)
# variant 1
print(os.curdir)
# variant 2
print(path_search_dir.cwd())
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the various ways of doing it. I might take one of those routes in the future!